# Boostrap 4 on mobile lets me scroll right to blank white screen (with footer)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On my homepage of the web app I'm making, I have photos that are scaled to `450px`. In mobile, everything fits perfectly on the screen, but the web app lets me scroll right to nothing, with the footer sticking to the bottom. I think it has something to do with my body and/or content and footer classes. I use a `div class="content"` for my photos, which centers them in the middle of three rows on the desktop version. I have this in my code already:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no">
```

And my classes look like this:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}

.footer {
    height:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    border-top: .5px solid #F5F5F5;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0pt;
    left: 0pt;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1.5px 1.5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -1.5px 1.5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px -1.5px 1.5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

You can see I tried the `overflow-x: hidden;` but that didn't work, and I've tried adjusting margins and padding on the body and row class, but that didn't work. Does anyone have a good solution?

Comment: if this is due to a div or something else that have too big width, we con't help you without the code. i suggest you open your page with an inspector and hover over your body then going down in order to figure out easily. also , css : *{border:1px solid red!important;} can easily work to find where is the issue

Comment: Can you provide a minimun example (adding the HTML markup) that simulates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

No rep to set it as comment, so am adding it as possible answer.

Your problem sound like the app in not really responsive (the meta tag doesn't make it such if your other HTML is not set up correctly), but cant be sure without looking at the html you have.

One suggestion would be to either put your entire code in the body in a container class 
or just the picture div :

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

This is what I usually use to make some part responsive (you also add it to the body).